# Can't stop IIS in windows 7

Tags: windows, iis

I can't seem to stop IIS (or whatever it is) running on port 80 on windows 7.

I've stopped all sites on IIS, as well as all application pools.

As the Administrator, I've tried:

```
net stop IIsadmin

net stop w3svc
```

When I telnet to localhost, on 80, I can attempt "GET index.html"

I get this  (as expected)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

When I telnet, but send garbage ( "asdf" ), I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2011 23:23:41 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 326
```

How can I make whatever this is running no longer run?

Comment: If you downvote, can you at least explain the reason for doing so?  If that isn't too much effort over clicking a button.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try

`net stop msdepsvc`

I've had that tie up port 80 before

EDIT:

Also, you can check what PID is tying up the port by using:

```
netstat -aon
```

Comment: Thank You! That was it.  It's also called "Web Deployment Agent Service" in Services.

Comment: Thanks for all the info! But none of these helped me :( I installed microsoft's SEO tools, and now WAMP does not work. WAMP Menu -> Apache -> Test Port 80 yields: `Your port 80 is actually used by Server : Microsoft-IIS/7.5` , but I cannot `net stop msdepsvc`. It says: `The service name is invalid.` and `netstat -aon` does not show any process for port 80. I cannot see "Web Deployment Agent Service" in task manager. **EDIT** the solution that worked for me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621592/cant-use-wamp-port-80-is-used-by-iis-7-5 (Unicorn's answer)

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
iisreset /stop
```

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/95826e7a-bac4-4e1f-bcb6-c52d49c9d7f4.mspx?mfr=true

Might not be IIS though.

The process might be a system process.  For example, see the post

http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1362841

In that case, it ended up being Windows Remote Management??

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall IIS from Windows or stop the service by going in "services.msc".

Comment: I think he just want's to stop it - not uninstall it.  uninstalling IIS seems mighty heavy handed to stop it.

Comment: services.msc will launch the gui console - I think he's looking for a cmdline command.

Comment: Looking at microsoft's article on this, it does look like he's going about it the right way:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236166

Comment: If you stop the service and restart it won't use the port again but ... maybe in command line yes. Good thinkin

Answer (score 1):

In my version of Windows 7 Professional, the service is called World Wide Web Publishing Service, and I only found it because of this thread, I started scrubbing my Services and could not find "Web Deployment Agent Service" and the closest thing was this. As soon as I stopped it, I was able to start Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the start menu and search for "Services", it should be the first result. Look for "Web Deployment Agent Service" and double click on this and then click "Stop", this works on Windows 7. If you never want it to startup, then edit the service via the "Startup type" drop down menu and choose "Disabled"

Answer (score 0):

For the record:
In my case it was an Microsoft SQL Server Service. I can't remember which one.

Answer (score 0):

I went through a different procedure. I searched on google and went to http://www.iis.net/configreference.

In short do as follow:

- go to %WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config
- open applicationHost.config with a good editor
- search (ctrl+f) 80. when found, replace it with something like 8080
- open a cli and type iisreset

you're done