# Can't use WAMP , port 80 is used by IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to use WAMP on Windows 7, my WAMP is online, but when I open localhost I get the welcome page of IIS 7.5, although I have uninstalled IIS 7.5 from my PC!

Apache server test says that port 80 is used my Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

MS Visual Studio 2010 was uninstalled a short while ago as well.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just uninstall IIS Express and leave the regular IIS installed?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i think i only uninstalled IIS Express , how can i uninstall the regular IIS ?

Comment: In "Computer", click "Uninstall or change a program", click "Turn Windows features on or off" and uncheck the "Internet Information Services" checkbox. When you click "Ok" it should remove itself.

Comment: Change IIS Port : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312136/how-do-i-change-iis-express-8-port-80-to-8080/56802079#56802079

Answer (score 37, accepted):

By default WampServer is installed to  port 80 which is already used by IIS. To set WampServer to use an open port, left click on the WampServer icon in the system tray and go to Apache > httpd.conf

Open the httpd.conf in Notepad. press ctrl+f and search for "Listen 80", change this line to "Listen 8080" (u can change this port as what you want), and then close and save the httpd.conf file.

Open a web browser and enter "[];, this will open the WampServer configuration page where you can configure Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

and some times this problem may occur because of skype also use 80 as default port 
hope this will help

Comment: Hi, I was trying to follow this solution but entering any combination of "[];, "[]; [];, etc. didn't bring me to any page. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Rajika's fix worked for me (changing Listen 80 to Listen 8080 in httpd.conf ...but only after I used "Put Online" in the WAMP icon popup (otherwise I got a "you don't have permission..." error). Note I'm running IIS 7.0 (which uses port 80) on Windows 7. I do some local ASP stuff as well, so I don't want to shut down IIS. I need both IIS and WAMP, this was the solution.

Comment: I put it online and finally wamp is green, the problem is that port 81 is forbidden.

Comment: I have changed to 8011 in http.config, then UNINSTALLED IIS, then changed back to 80 and now works.

Comment: "PS: Don't forget to restart the WAMP once fixing the errors", after change port to 8080, I exit "AestanTrayMenu" which is WAMP's process name and restart it and success become green

Comment: This isn't really a direct answer to the problem. IIS takes over port 80 even when you disable it. Saying how to prevent IIS from reserving that port and allowing your prefered webserver to listen on port 80 would be a much better answer.

Comment: I got WAMP to work using the other answer that Devrath provided.  I wanted to find a true solution to the problem that meant having WAMP work with its defaults, and I wanted no other web services running, so I disabled IIS which I had never really setup, configure, or started on Windows 10 Professional anyway..

Comment: Listen 80 was not there in my httpd.conf

i changed Listen  0.0.0.0:80 and Listen [::0]:80 and ServerName localhost:80 . all there 80 to 8080 and worked for me.

Answer (score 136):

***I had lot of problems with this error*** (Thanks to Microsoft -- Grrr!!)

*Finally found the solution ..... I am sharing this solution*

There are couple of ways to stop IIS 7.5

- **Best one is:**

  Open a CMD prompt (as Admin) and type this:

  iisreset /stop
  *Here is a snapshot:*

  [image]
- **Next option if you still cannot stop the IIS 7.5**

  Try [this video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGhyYmbJS7A).
- **Final option is to change the port number as the last option
  httpd.conf**

**PS:** Don't forget to restart the WAMP once fixing the errors

---

***You can also***

Just disable and stop the *World Wide Web Publishing Service* (This shuts down IIS forever) - - -(You need to use **Run** from the starting point in windows):

```
sc config w3svc start= disabled
net stop w3svc
```

If you don't want it disabled, but manual instead, replace disabled by demand (don't remove space).

Comment: This is really the best answer +1. Stopping the IIS (either temporary or permanently) should be prior and changing the apache port should be the final (not the best) option.

Comment: Stopped IIS temporarily with this solution. But the second command doesn't execute but displays details of the command itself [Description, Usage, Options). Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using **Windows 10**, as I am, and the port is occupied by Microsoft-IIS/10.0, change the **lines 62** and **63**, of the `httpd.conf`, from:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

To:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```

As the people here suggested.

And also, change the **line 221**, from:

```
ServerName localhost:80
```

To:

```
ServerName localhost:8080
```

Now, your host will be available at http://localhost:8080/.

Answer (score 12):

1. Go to *`Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services`* or simply type
   `services.msc` in run  to open a list of all windows services.
2. Find **`World Wide Web Publishing Service`** and `stop` it. (if you want to disable it permanently you can change its start up type from `automatically` to `disabled`).

That's All

Comment: +1. This is what the bottom part of @Devrath's answer does, just in a nicer way. No need to mess around with ports or config files or anything else - the problem is the "hidden" IIS bundled inside the `World Wide Web Publishing Service`.

Answer (score 6):

This could also be an issue of port 80 being used by "Web Deployment Agent Service".
you can stop it from administrative tools->services and free up that port.
as shown [here](http://wampservers.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/hello-world/)

Answer (score 6):

goto services and stop the "**World Wide Web Publishing Service**"
after restart the wamp server.
after that start the "**World Wide Web Publishing Service**"

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can just change the port to to any number. For instance change `Listen 80` to `Listen 81` in the `httpd.conf` file. Now try with `http://localhost:81` and it will respond on port 81!!

Comment: This has helped me partially however on the homepage  http://localhost:81 i cannot see any of my php files that are present under C://wamp/www/Php_Files/demo.php.Also when i try to run my php file it gives me error :The requested URL /Php_Files/demo.php was not found on this server.Can some body help me on this?Also i have installed wampserver on port 81 since skype has taken port 80.

Answer (score 3):

After uninstalling IIS on Windows 7, I continued to have IIS Welcome page.
The solution was to clear the cache of my web browsers.
It works fine now.
I didn't change anything else.
Sorry for my english, if it is not perfect.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can also uncheck the IIS services from control panel add or remove programs going for windows add or remove components.

Answer (score 2):

Left Click on wamp go to apache> select http.config

change LISTEN:80 to what ever you want you can choose any value of 4 digit like 1311,8000,9999 etc

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a month ago on Windows 10. Whenever I tried to access http://localhost/ it led me to the IIS page. I tried removing the IIS feature from windows features. Once I was sure it was gone, I tried running XAMPP, but it still did not work. I did not want to mess with the configuration files. But from this, I was quite sure it had something to do with my web browser. So, deleted the cache from the web browser I was using (Google Chrome).

To do so, I went to:

Chrome > Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Privacy > Clear browsing data > Clear Cached images and files.

Its almost the same process for any web browsers. Right after that, I was able to run XAMPP without any problem!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I just installed **WAMP 3** on **Windows 10** and did not have Apache in the WampServer system tray options.

But the httpd.conf file is located here:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\conf\
```

In that folder, open `httpd.conf` with a text editor. Then go to line 62-63 and change **80** to **8080** like this:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```

Then go to the WampServer icon in the system tray and right-click > Exit, then Open WampServer again, and it should now turn green.

Now go to `localhost:8080` to see your server config page.

Answer (score 1):

Google search of "remove iis from port 80" leads here currently.
Instead of removing IIS, here are the steps to just [stop IIS from listening on port 80](https://caarmeltechiez.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/stop-iis-from-using-port-80/):

STEP 1:
Open IIS Window. You can do this by, simply hitting the ‘Windows’ key and typing in ‘IIS’ or ‘Internet Information Services’. The result will be shown up there. Click it, you will get the window opened for you.

STEP 2:
On the ‘Connections’ pane, click the default one to expand it. Usually (PC-NAME(PC-NAME\user), where ‘PC-NAME’ is your PC name, and ‘user’ is the username.

STEP 3:
Click ‘Sites’ and expand it.
Now select ‘Default Web Site’.
On the ‘Actions’ pane, click ‘Bindings’ under the ‘Edit Site’.

STEP 4:
Now a window named ‘Site Binding Opens. Click ‘http’ and then click edit.
Change the port to another number, say 8000 and click ‘Ok’.

Answer (score 0):

remove iis server and run Apache  OR run Apache in a different port

to remove iir [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321141/)

or you can change apache port by go to httpd.config and change port:80 to something else

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although I am sure that you have the best intentions to help, a recommendation to replace the whole technology stack cannot be reasonably considered an answer to a question. Good luck with the site!

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me once: I uninstalled the IIS, and the port 80 still was used. Well the problem was that also I had the `Report Service` of the `Sql Server 2012` installed, so I stopped that service and the problems solves.

See [Stop Or Uninstall IIS for running Wamp Server (Apache) on default port (:80)](https://superuser.com/questions/808511/stop-or-uninstall-iis-for-running-wamp-server-apache-on-default-port-80) question for more details.

Hope this helps some body, as it help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Left Click on wamp go to apache> select http.config
Listen [::0]:8080

Answer (score 0):

**I don't recommend changing apaches port itself, because it will need you remember changed port. Its also headache to tell your co-developers about port change.**

Go to windows features(By searching turn on or off windows features)
-> Find Internet information services(IIS) and uncheck if it checked.
   Please make a note when you disable it FTP server/ client will not work.(incase you are 
   using it, change httpd.conf as giovannipds 's answer)
-> If still port is not free, then change skype port through skype settings.

thanks,
[image]