# wamp server does not start: Windows 7, 64Bit

Tags: apache, wamp, windows-7-x64

I am trying to install wamp server (following is the exact setup name) on windows 7, 64Bit OS. But it never starts, icon stays in orange color meaning some services did not start.

```
wampserver2.2e-php5.3.13-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-x64
```

I did not find any solution.

```
No skype, port 80 is not in use.
```

In windows services, when I try to start wampapache service manually, it throws following error:

> Windows could not start the wampapache service on Local Computer.
>   Error 1053: The service did not respond ot the start or control request in a timely fashion.

```
apache_error.log is empty.
```

Things use to work fine in windows XP.

Comment: did you try running it as Administrator ? (Right click, run as administrator)

Comment: Could it be some kind of missing dependency DLL for wampapache?  Run [Depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the services that aren't starting and see if there is a side-by-side or missing DLL issue.  Unless you've tried that already.

Comment: You just need VC++ 2015, if you change your php version to the newest version you will get the error for it. this is why apache has php dependency error.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

My solution to fix that problem was the following:

Start > search > cmd.exe (Run as administrator)

Inside the Command Prompt (cmd.exe) type:

```
cd c:/wamp/bin/apache/ApacheX.X.X/bin
httpd.exe -e debug
```

**Note that the ApacheX.X.X is the version of the Apache wamp is running.

This should output what the apache server is doing.  The error that causes Apache from loading should be in there.  My problem was that httpd.conf was trying to load a DLL that was missing or was corrupted (php5apache2_4.dll).  As soon as I overwrote this file, I restarted Wamp and everything ran smooth.

Comment: This helped me find that port 80 was not available, then the next answer finished the solution.

Comment: I my case msvcr100.dll was missing and i downloaded from here "http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?msvcr100" and placed in system32 folder. As soon as i place that file wamp icon turns green by its own !!!

Comment: Also SSL could have an issue. In httpd.conf comment `# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` or it could fire: `(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443` and 
`(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443`

Comment: This is the only and best answer. Whatever is wrong with apache, any error logs are dumped using this command

Comment: Worked great. Was because I had changed my routers IP address from 192.168.1.69 to 192.168.0.15 and had a mention of this in my http.conf file

Comment: You don't need to overwrite it just install vc++ 2015. (You think wampserver would release a corrupt file for this long?)

Answer (score 21):

I solved the problem this way:

- On the orange WAMP icon, click Apache > Service > Test Port 80. Came back with "Port 80 not accessible -- (could be Skype)"
- Sign out from Skype and close program.
- Click orange icon and hit Apache > Service > Install Service
- Click orange icon and hit Apache > Service > Start Service
- Click orange icon and hit Put Online
- Icon turns green and service is started and online

Comment: All that you posted above plus checking Apache & Windows logs for other possible errors. (multiple Apache instances or other apps on port 80)

Comment: This was the solution! SKYPE >:E

Comment: NO!!!!! **INSTALL SERVICE+PUT ONLINE** not needed. just exit skype (or better, in skype options>connections> set another port instead of 80

Comment: Also stop the apache (not wampapache) service if you had started it,

Comment: also can see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621592/cant-use-wamp-port-80-is-used-by-iis-7-5

Comment: Both this and the accepted answer helped. In my case there was another version of Apache running that was overriding port 80. Disabled it in services manager and everything worked again. Upvoted both answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps (taken from [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvgUxpIurNU&feature=youtu.be)).

1. Quit Skype
2. Uninstall IIS

   - Go to control panel
   - Refer to PROGRAMS AND FEATURES
   - Go to TURN WINDOWS FEATURES ON OR OFF
   - Look for INTERNET information service
   - Uninstall

Comment: Here's a link if you don't want to close Skype:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705005/how-to-solve-wamp-and-skype-conflict-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

You just need Visual C++ runtime 2015 installed, if you change your php version to the newest version you will get the error for it. this is why apache has php dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache error log. I had this error "[error] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : could not open transfer log file C:/wamp/logs/access.log. Unable to open logs"
Then I rename my "access.log" to other name, you can delete if you don't need/never see your access log. Then restart your apache service. This happen because the file size too big. I think if you trying to open this file using notepad, it will not open, I tried to open that before. Hope it help.

Comment: In my case (since apache never started properly) the error log file didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Windows event viewer to try to get more information about the errors : in the "Application" section of the Windows logs, there is a good chance you will find error messages from Apache. (At least I found what was wrong in my case there !)

Answer (score 0):

I navigated to C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin run httpd and the apache (pink and white icon) loads into the system tray. The orange W also turned green.

The apacheapache service wasn't running, it wasn't on the services list (start > type services) which is why it's orange not green.

Solution: A re-install worked for me.

My version is:
WAMPSERVER (64Bits & PHP 5.4) 2.4
Apache : 2.4.4
MySQL : 5.6.12 
PHP : 5.4.12 
PHPMyAdmin : 4.0.4 
SqlBuddy : 1.3.3 
XDebug : 2.2.3
http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

For me it got resolved using following link:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/wamp-server-not-getting-started-problem/

where i was using skype and Wamp both installed and running

Comment: In Skype, goto Tools > Options… > Advanced > Connection and uncheck the checkbox which says “Use Port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections”