# Unable to start Wamp server in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I recently moved from XP to win7 64 bit OS. While I tried installing Wamp server, it popped out a error message

> The program cant start because MSVCR100.dll is missing from your
>   computer. try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

Skype is not been installed on my pc. Port 80 is free. Still unable to figure out whats the error in my configuration. Also heard that Downloading External DLL files is harmful. 
Please help me in fixing this issue. 
Also I installed VC redistribution package. 
Wamp server icon is orange in color suggesting error in configuration. Any help will be hihgly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Download the dll from the internet (Microsoft website) manually, then unpack it and put it to windows/system32 folder

Comment: Isnt it harmful to download external dll files and place it in our system32 folder ?

Comment: It can be found on Microsoft website inside Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable. Do you still have same error after installing C Runtime library?

Comment: After installing vc++ package, it installed without any errors. But still the icon is orange and localhost is not working

Comment: After this fix, the final solution included these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303216/wamp-server-does-not-start-windows-7-64bit

Answer (score 0):

You should [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) Microsoft® C Runtime Library.

Comment: installed it. but still not helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have not followed the prerequisites that are displayed BEFORE installation begins. You have not read and validated Next. Yet the text is very explicit

--- Installation of Wampserver ---

BEFORE proceeding with the installation of Wampserver, you must ensure that certain elements are installed on your system, otherwise Wampserver will absolutely not run, and in addition, the installation will be faulty and you need to remove Wampserver BEFORE installing the elements that were missing.

Make sure you are "up to date" in the redistributable packages VC9, VC10, VC11, VC13 and VC14 Even if you think you are up to date, install each package as administrator and if message "Already installed", validate Repair.

The following packages (VC9, VC10, VC11) are imperatively required to Wampserver 2.4, 2.5 and 3.0, even if you use only Apache and PHP versions VC11 and VC14 is required for PHP 7 and Apache 2.4.17

-- VC9 Packages (Visual C++ 2008 SP1)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092

-- VC10 Packages (Visual C++ 2010 SP1)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523

-- VC11 Packages (Visual C++ 2012 Update 4)

The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

-- VC13 Packages[/b] (Visual C++ 2013[)

The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

-- VC14 Packages (Visual C++ 2015)

The two files vcredist_x86.exe and vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:

http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=48145

If you have a 64-bit Windows, you must install both 32 and 64bit versions, even if you do not use Wampserver 64 bit.