# WAMPserver 3.0.4 on Windows 10 (64 bit): Apache server (httpd service) did not start

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I recently installed WAMPserver 3.0.4 x64 bit on my Windows 10 64 bit OS.

**Issue:**
Apache server (2.4.18) did not start with the following error message:

```
Could not execute menu item (internal error)
[Exception] Could not perform service action:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
```

*Similar Question was raised before on stackoverflow, but the resolutions posted there didn't help in my case.
(I've mentioned the details below).*

***Diagnosis***:

**Step 1:** 
Tested port 80, since my Apache server was using this one. Here is what the test returned:

```
***** Test which uses port 80 *****



===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====




Test for TCP Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol



===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====


Your port 80 is not actually used.
```

**Step 2:** 
Even though the result showed that Port 80 was not an issue, I tried to change port number from 80 to 8080. 
Still received the same error. The test showed that Port 8080 was not being used either. 
So, the issue is clearly not with the Port number.

**Step 3:** 
Changed the PHP version from 5.6 to 7 through the WAMP server menu. This didn't produce any different result.

**Step 4:** 
As per the most voted suggestion on the same error on a previous discussion, I typed 'httpd -e debug' on the cmd prompt:
(link to previous discussion: [wamp server does not start: Windows 7, 64Bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303216/wamp-server-does-not-start-windows-7-64bit))

```
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\bin>**httpd -e debug**
```

After executing the script for a brief moment, the process hung up. I am listing the last 3 statements that showed up:

```
[Wed Sep 07 19:57:35.680559 2016] [so:debug] [pid 8496:tid 428] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module userdir_module from C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/modules/mod_userdir.so
[Wed Sep 07 19:57:35.691570 2016] [so:debug] [pid 8496:tid 428] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module vhost_alias_module from C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
[Wed Sep 07 19:57:35.712582 2016] [so:debug] [pid 8496:tid 428] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module php7_module from C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.4/php7apache2_4.dll
```

The last one says that php7_module was loaded from 
`/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.4/php7apache2_4.dll`
before freezing the command prompt.

This was the same file mentioned as the culprit in the earlier discussion. 
I thought that this must be the culprit in my case as well.

**Step 5:**
Downloaded the file `php7apache2_4.dll` from 
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69801 
and put it in my `/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.4/` location

The error still persists and I am not sure what else to do?

*I had also tried:*

- Rebooting the system
- Running the WAMP Server as an administrator
- Going to Apache > Service Administration > Install Service

Nothing has worked yet!

Comment: Skype will oddly use port 80 for me. I have to close skype and then open wamp and then it's fine. Another thing that may sniping port 80 is IIS. Google how to turn that off in Windows 10, just to make sure that service isn't running as well.

Comment: @Blake SKYE can be configured so it will not use port 80 and 443

Comment: Update: Someone suggested me to check the latest version for Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio. I installed the latest from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 and this resolved my issue. Thanks for taking out your time to try to answer to my issue.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just found that option. Thanks for the tip. I just never bothered to look :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read the dialog that is shown as part of the install about making sure you have the full set of Microsoft C/C++ Runtime libraries installed.

Windows 10 does not come with them all installed

--- Installation of Wampserver ---

BEFORE proceeding with the installation of Wampserver, you must ensure that certain elements are installed on your system, otherwise Wampserver will absolutely not run, and in addition, the installation will be faulty and you need to remove Wampserver BEFORE installing the elements that were missing.
    Make sure you are "up to date" in the redistributable packages VC9, VC10, VC11, VC13 and VC14
    See --- Visual C++ Packages below.

--- Do not install Wampserver OVER an existing version, follow the advice:

[Install a new version of Wampserver:](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606)

If you install Wampserver over an existing version, not only it will not work, but you risk losing your existing databases.

--- Install Wampserver in a folder at the root of a disk, for example `C:\wamp` or `D:\wamp`. Take an installation path that does not include spaces or diacritics; 
    Therefore, no installation in `c:\Program Files\` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\`

We must BEFORE installing, disable or close some applications:
- Close Skype or force not to use port 80
  Item No. 04 of the [Wampserver TROUBLESHOOTING TIPS:](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915)

- Disable IIS
  Item No. 08 of the [Wampserver TROUBLESHOOTING TIPS:](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915)

If these prerequisites are not in place, Press the Cancel button to cancel the installation, then apply the prerequisites and restart the installation.

--- Visual C++ Packages ---

The MSVC runtime libraries VC9, VC10, VC11 are required for Wampserver 2.4, 2.5 and 3.0, even if you use only Apache and PHP versions with VC11. Runtimes VC13, VC14 is required for PHP 7 and Apache 2.4.17

-- VC9 Packages (Visual C++ 2008 SP1)

[32bit from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582)
and  [64bit from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092)

-- VC10 Packages (Visual C++ 2010 SP1)

[32bit from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)
and 
 [64bit from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

-- VC11 Packages (Visual C++ 2012 Update 4)
The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page: [32bit and 64bit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

-- VC13 Packages] (Visual C++ 2013[)
The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page: [32bit and 64bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

-- VC14 Packages (Visual C++ 2015)
The two files vcredist_x86.exe and vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page: [32bit and 64bit](http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

If you have a **64-bit Windows**, you must **install both 32 and 64bit versions**, even if you do not use Wampserver 64 bit.

This is item number 20 of [TROUBLESHOOTING TIPS of Wampserver:](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915)

**ALSO** remember you must install WAMPServer "As an Administator" and also run it that way.

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly - you mentioned excellent tips on how to proceed in case of WAMPserver failure. I will keep them in mind.

Comment: Thanks, first remove wamp, follow steps, reboot e installation again wamp. Succes

Answer (score 0):

Update: Someone suggested me to check the latest version for Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio. 
I installed the latest from 
microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 
and this resolved my issue. 
Thanks to those who took out their time to try to answer my question.