# wampserver the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00005b

Tags: apache, wampserver

I installed wampserver but when I try to runt it I get this error message and the icon color is orange:

the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00005b

I have windows 7 64 bit so I installed wampserver 64,

also I tried solving the problem by changing the Listen in httpd.conf from:

Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80

to

Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080

but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you also read the Install dialog that suggested you need all these MSVC Runtime libraries? As a 64bit Windows user you need both the 32bit and 64bit versions of all of these!!!

Comment: [See this post for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377255/wampserver-3-0-4-on-windows-10-64-bit-apache-server-httpd-service-did-not-s/39377626#39377626)