# Error when i open wamp server, the application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)

Tags: wamp

I recently opened Wamp server after a long time I didn't touch it. It was fine back then, but when I try to open Wamp server now, I get an error that says

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142).

In addition, the wamp icon is orange, while back then, it was green.

I have tried to search for a solution on the internet, but I wasn't able to find.

I have also noticed that when I try to open phpMyAdmin, the page says

> #2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>   The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)

But i'm able to open my localhost start page (the one with the loaded extentions list).

Thanks for helping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon/21678795#21678795

Comment: Sorry for the **Huge** dellay, I have been very busy, but this doesn't seems to solve the problem and the "start/resume" icons of the apache and mySQL are grey, but as for the mySQL-> service tab, the three top icons are grey.

Comment: Then try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377255/wampserver-3-0-4-on-windows-10-64-bit-apache-server-httpd-service-did-not-s/39377626#39377626

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for your time, i re installed wamp, and it got fixed :)
Good day/night!

Comment: If OP's link is out of date you might try this thread, which may be a better solution for some: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901015/wampserver-apache-httpd-exe-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000014

Answer (score 13):

Same error after creators update 1703 (Windows 10).

[image]

Error: *httpd.exe was unable to start correctly*
Error code: **0xc0000142**

I'll do a quick google search and see what this is about. I will get back for sure.

**UPDATE:** ***SOLUTION***
WAMP has released a cumulative update to fix this. It is strongly encouraged that you apply this update after you’ve installed WAMP.
Wampserver update 3.0.8. [Sourceforge](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wampserver/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Updates/wampserver3_x86_x64_update3.0.8.exe).

Once you apply this fix, you will be able to start (Apache) WAMP normally.

Comment: Hi Richard. What happen to my files if I update my WAMP to 3.0.8? Is my file still there?

Comment: As far as I remember it will not affect your files or any of your settings. You're good to go.

Comment: That's great, I'll try it later.

Comment: Awesome answer , perfect solution and saved lots of time and efforts, Many thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

Actually this error relate to Windows Firewall.
You can go to "Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed apps" after that click change settings and in Allow apps and feature find "Appache HTTP Server" and check public then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your Windows Firewall Services is not running.

I faced the same issue after installing 64bit Wamp. While installing I was not prompted to allow http daemon by the firewall service.

Unsure what to do, I installed the 32bit Wamp & the firewall service prompted me to allow the http daemon.

Wamp started showing green!!