# WAMP server on windows10 unable to run Apache server

Tags: apache, windows-10, wamp

When I run WAMP server I get next error:

[image]

I tried disabling windows defender, installing 32 bit version and updating whole WAMP server. What to do?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the install that say you must ensure that all the required MSVC runtimes are installed before installing WAMPServer?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377255/wampserver-3-0-4-on-windows-10-64-bit-apache-server-httpd-service-did-not-s/39377626#39377626

Comment: Also there is an upgrade available to version 3.0.9 I suggest you apply it. It will only affect WAMPServer code and not change the APache/MySQL/PHP versions you are using. You can [find the upgrade here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) its easier to navigate than sourceforge

Comment: YES, thank you guys, somehow missed that thread, works now. Off-topic: windows 10 is trash.

Comment: ___missed that thread___ And all the prompts in the install script. Dont blame W10 for your mistakes

Comment: well yeah, I never had any problems with any OS, however with w10 you have to do dumb shit like this.