# HTTP The service is starting or stopping. Please try again later error on windows 7

Tags: windows-services, httpservice

I used following command to stop the HTTP service

```
net stop http /y
```

And I got following error message:

> The service is starting or stopping.  Please try again later.

Now the HTTP service is in a in-between state. Its neither stopped nor starting. What should i do?

I read some similar issues but they are not helping.

[Can't stop IIS in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910100/cant-stop-iis-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to **kill it via the Task Manager.**

Right-click on taskbar -> Start Task Manager Go to  Process tab
If you can find the service under the Processes tab:

Right click and select "End Process"
If you don't see it under Processes (or don't know which is the process for the service you want to kill),

While on the Processes tab

Check "Show processes from all users" in the lower left 
Then "View" menu and choose "Select Columns"
Check "PID" and hit OK
Go to the services tab to find the PID of the service you want to kill
Go back to Processes tab and Right-click -> End Process**strong text**

Copied the answer from the https://superuser.com/questions/489949/force-windows-7-service-to-stop 
and it worked for me.

Comment: So you recommend killing the System process? That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I know it's an old topic, but why it's a bad idea?

Comment: I had this issue with SharePoint 2010 Timer. This helped me out. Thank you verry much.

Answer (score 4):

There are probably some processes that have open handles to `\Device\Http\*`.

You need close these handles or processes (e.g. in Process Explorer) to let the HTTP service stop.

Answer (score 1):

I did this (on Windows 10) and can be done on Windows 7 (see below):

- Turn on the windows feature the *IIS Management Console*.
- Windows search for "IIS Manager"
- From the *Manage Server Menu* on the right, select *"Stop"*

it worked. (e.g. free up the port 80 )

I checked that the same can be done on Windows 7 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me (I am using Windows 10):

1. Restarted the PC - It reset the "starting and stopping state" and started Http service - Irrespective of OS worth trying
2. Opened command prompt in the administrator mode
3. Http Service is running by default, can check using command ->  Net Start HTTP
4. Run command -> Net Stop HTTP
   Following message is displayed
   The following services depend on the HTTP Service service.
   Stopping the HTTP Service service also stops these services.

   WWW Publishing Service
   W3C Logging Service
   SSDP search
   Feature Search Resource Release
   Function Search Provider Host
5. Upon entering 'Y', HTTP Service stops